# Force implementation of meta data that can be accessed without instantiation of class

Tags: c#, interface, metadata

`const` and `static` type properties/fields can be accessed without creating an object of a class:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TemporaryTests
{
  [Test]
  public void TmpTest1()
  {
    Assert.AreEqual("Name", TestClass.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual("Description", TestClass.Description);
  }

  private class TestClass
  {
    public const string Name = "Name";
    public static string Description = "Description";
  }
}
```

Is it possible to define those properties/fields in an Interface, so that a class implementing that interface implements that field?

What I am trying to accomplish is have every class, that implements a certain interface, supply a way to access their "spoken name" and description (each class should have its own implementation / meta information)

---

*Edit:* Just to be clear: I do realise that i cant put consts or statics in interfaces, as my research before posting here uncovered already. What i want to know is if there is a way to force a class that implements a certain interface to contain meta information that can be accessed without having to create an object of that class.

Comment: No, there isn't - yet. It's possible that C# 8 will have something along those lines though. See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164

Comment: Thanks for that (incredibly fast) answer! It will take me a while to read through those proposals. :D

Answer (score 0):

The following code could be an alternative solution.

```
public interface IDesc
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
}

public static class Desc<T> where T : IDesc, new()
{
    public static string Name
    {
        get
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty("Name");

            return property.GetValue(new T()) as string;
        }
    }

    public static string Description
    {
        get
        {
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty("Description");

            return property.GetValue(new T()) as string;
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass : IDesc
{
    public string Name { get { return "name of class"; } }
    public string Description { get { return "description"; } }
}
```

Usage

```
var name = Desc<MyClass>.Name;
var description = Desc<MyClass>.Description;
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but this creates an object of the class for every access `new T()`, which is exactly what I didn't want to need to do (as stated in the question).

I'll use a factory pattern for now, handling that meta information on registration of the class at the factory. :(